aiogram: в dispatcher нет message что делать
много смотрел про aiogram, даже тут нашел программу, в которой в aiogram3 предлагают поставить хендлер так: @dp.message(Command('start')) (по синтаксису не важно сейчас). Начал писать программу а aiogram пишет что у класса Dispatcher нет message. Ну и соответственно вопрос: как сделать хендлер на async defы? или будет проще перейти на aiogram2?
Вот что у меня написано в коде:
import asyncio
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
token = 'TOKEN'
bot = Bot(token)
dp = Dispatcher()


@dp.message(Command('start'))
async def botStart(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('hello')



async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

Ошибка:
Unresolved reference 'Command'
если что я на пайчарме работаю

Дополните Ваш вопрос ошибкой и куском кода, на который указывает данная ошибка, чтобы лучше понять в чем ошибка

Прилоите полный текст ошибки

а все я понял, там надо command импортировать отдельно:
from aiogram.filters import Command
